# Dependent Nested For Loops in Bash

Tags: java, bash, shell

I am trying to implement a nested for loop in bash where the inner loop uses the current value of the outer loop in its range but I am getting this error "/drawgraph.sh: line 19: {0..1}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..1}")"

Here is my code:

```
for i in {0..499}
do
  for j in {0..$i}
  do
    # other code
  done
done
```

Here's a java analogy for what I'm trying to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 499; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Comment: Brace expansion happens before parameter expansion, and `{0..$i}` is not a valid brace expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `((i=0;i<499;i++))` instead of `{0..499}`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0;i<499;i++))
do
  for ((j=0;j<i;j++))
  do
    echo "$i $j"
  done
done
```

If you want to use the array syntax you should use `$(seq 0 $i)` instead of `{0..$i}`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..499}
do
  for j in $(seq 0 $i)
  do
    echo "$i $j"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that your current approach does not work.

Does anything prevent you from using normal C-style loops?

```
for ((i = 0; i < 499; i++)); 
do
  for ((j = 0; j < i; j++)); 
  do
    # use $i and $j as you like
  done
done
```

Adding some evidence here, since it is not [the first time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55392/in-bash-is-it-possible-to-use-an-integer-variable-in-the-loop-control-of-a-for) this question has been asked. As the answer states, "*brace expansion occurs before variables are expanded*".